# How to add the Done button above the keyboard for iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, keyboard

As per the screenshot below is what I want to achieve. Note the location of the Done button.
In React Native, we have the `returnKeyType` prop for `textInput` but that sets the value of the button at the bottom right.

I had a look at this package;
https://github.com/ardaogulcan/react-native-keyboard-accessory

Which does seem like it could work but don't know if there is a better way to do this.
Plus with the amount of input boxes, could take a while for me to refactor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you import Keyboard from react-native, then add this at the top of your code. Surround your code with DismissKeyboard so the keyboard will close when you click anywhere on the screen

```
const DismissKeyboard = ({children}) => (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>{children}</TouchableWithoutFeedback> 
);

<DismissKeyboard> Code </DisissKeyboard>
```

Comment: And that makes sense - the problem is that a requirement for a project I am working on must visually look like the above screenshot where the Done button is above the keyboard. I am at a point where I think I should just write my own component that does this. Find it weird this isn't available for React Native or hard to find.

Comment: Hmm ok, I don't think there is something that's already available. Best choice would be to design your own component.